Error trying to connect Databricks Warehouse via Hashicorp Boundary Session
I am trying to connect Databricks Warehouse via Hashicorp Boundary Session
I have created host on Hashicorp Boundary for Databricks Warehouse Host and started a session to connect to it.
When I try the URL in DataGrip to connect to this data warehouse, I am getting following error:
DBMS: SparkSQL (ver. 3.1.1)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
Driver: DatabricksJDBC (ver. 02.06.36.1062, JDBC4.2)
[Databricks][JDBCDriver](500593) Communication link failure. Failed to connect to server. Reason: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake.

Here is the URL I am trying to connect: jdbc:databricks://127.0.0.1:63771/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=/sql/1.0/warehouses/a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8;

It looks like your certificate missing 127.0.0.1 as the host. name. Could you try to specify mapping of your host to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file?

@VasiliiChernov I tried that. Doesn't work

This is already a raised issue for the datagrip and related IDE's from JetBrains, similar is happening while trying to connect to PostgreSQL as well.
PostgresSQL wihle trying to connect to DB server
Issue Youtrack Link : Youtrack for DataGrip
